# How to console inside of emacs?

Tags: shell

I have spacemacs and a problem I have compared to using terminal+vim is that I could do everything in the terminal : create files, directories, whatever and whenever I need to edit a file I just type `vim file`. Now to use spacemacs I basically have to tab to exmaces and type the path to the file I want to edit.

So I think you would need to console inside emacs, is there such service ?

Comment: Wrt your tagging this with `terminal-mode`: That's about running Emacs in a terminal/console. You're asking about running a shell inside Emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`M-x shell`

See the Emacs manual, node [Interactive Shell](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Interactive-Shell.html).